# Remove mat-btn overlay on click?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I have a mat-menu dropdown, having a mat-button in it.
I want to remove the overlay that appears once user clicks the dropdown.

I am able to remove the hover overlay by writing the following css.

```
.no-hover-effect ::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This is how html code for mat-button looks like.

```
    <div class="mat-menu-wrapper mat-menu-size" [matMenuTriggerFor]="abc">
      <button mat-button class="mat-button no-hover-effect">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper"><span class="mat-menu-text">
            xyz</span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #abc="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>
          xyz
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          xyz
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-ui">arrow_drop_down
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are able to remove the overlay what is the problem here then ?

Comment: @dota2pro Overlay is removed on hovering, but not on clicking, that's the issue.

Comment: I think what you are calling "overlay" is actually the ripple effect of mat-button. just add `[disableRipple]="true"` to your `mat-button` and it's gone.

Comment: @Vahid great it worked thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to disable the ripple effect of mat-button. As mentioned [here](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api#MatButton) you can disable it by adding `[disableRipple]="true"` to your `mat-button`.

Learn [more about ripple effect](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview)